# Create React App (CRA) with Typescript from wmonk vs Microsoft?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I'm trying to use CRA with Typescript to initialize my React project with Typescript. I googled "create react app typescript", and two providers, wmonk and Microsoft, showed up with their own Github repository. I created React app with each of them and they made the same React project architecture.

What's the difference between those twos? Which one should I better stick to?

Answer (score 0):

They're the same; [Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter) uses [wmonk/create-react-app-typescript](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) under the covers. The ms repo is really just an example, all the heavy lifting is handled by wmonk's project.

Comment: Just to make sure, whatever I use to start a new React project, the implicit configuration will be the same?